# Loop for automatically webscrape data from few pages

Tags: python, web-scraping

Since I've been trying to figure out how to make a loop and I couldn't make it from another threads, I need help. I am totally new to this so editing existing codes is hard for me.

I am trying to web scrape data from website. Here's what I've done so far, but I have to insert pages "manually". I want it to automatically scrape prices in zl/m2 from 1 to 20 pages for example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link=("https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-mam-do-wynajecia/wi,100.html?strona=1")
page = requests.get(link).text

link1=("https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-mam-do-wynajecia/wi,100.html?strona=2")
page1 = requests.get(link1).text

link2=("https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-mam-do-wynajecia/wi,100.html?strona=3")
page2 = requests.get(link2).text

pages=page+page1+page2+page3+page4+page5+page6

soup = BeautifulSoup(pages, 'html.parser')
price_box = soup.findAll('p', attrs={'class':'list__item__details__info details--info--price'})

prices=[]

for i in range(len(price_box)):
prices.append(price_box[i].text.strip())

prices
```

I've tried with this code, but got stuck. I don't know what should I add to get output from 20 pages at once and how to save it to csv file.

```
npages=20
baselink="https://ogloszenia.trojmiasto.pl/nieruchomosci-mam-do-wynajecia/wi,100.html?strona="
for i in range (1,npages+1):
link=baselink+str(i)
page = requests.get(link).text
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is whitespace sensitive, so the code block of any loops needs to be indented, like so:

```
for i in range (1,npages+1):
    link=baselink+str(i)
    page = requests.get(link).text
```

If you want all of the pages in a single string (so you can use the same approach as with your pages variable above), you can append the strings together in your loop:

```
pages = ""
for i in range (1,npages+1):
    link=baselink+str(i)
    pages += requests.get(link).text
```

To create a csv file with your results, you can look into the csv.writer() method in python's built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), but I usually find it easier to write to a file using print():

```
with open(samplefilepath, mode="w+") as output_file:
    for price in prices:
        print(price, file=output_file)
```

`w+` tells python to create the file if it doesn't exist and overwrite if it does exist. `a+` would append to the existing file if it exists

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted to achieve. Seems like I missed only "+=". Thanks. 
Do you know any way to save it directly to csv file?

Comment: added sample csv output. If you're using Mac, you're path would look something like r"/users/daniellong/Documents/output.csv". For windows, slashes are the other way. r"C:\users\daniellong\Documents\output.csv"